# pass checkbox data from form to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a admin page where i can edit/delete entry posts. I have just added the checkbox with input name of loest..

In mysql i added a column with the name of loest, and TYPE: TINYINT, and NULL: YES.

I work in Dreamweaver cs6.

My question is: How do i pass the state of the checkbox into my database?

My form looks like this:

```
 <?php do { ?>
            <tr>
              <td><h5><?php echo $row_insert_data['id']; ?></h5></td>
              <td><?php echo $row_insert_data['fejlmeldt_dato']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row_insert_data['aarsag']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row_insert_data['loest_dato']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row_insert_data['TIMESTAMP']; ?></td>
              <td><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $row_insert_data['id']; ?>"><img src="images/006-pencil.png" width="16" height="16"></a></td>
              <td><a href="del.php?id=<?php echo $row_insert_data['id']; ?>"><img src="images/glyphicons-17-bin.png" width="15" height="21"></a></td>
              <td><input name="loest" type="checkbox" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } while ($row_insert_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($insert_data)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the checkbox in a form like below:

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
<input name="loest" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

and in post.php check box result will be like below:

```
if (empty($_POST['loest']))
 echo $_POST['loest'] = "0";//0 will be assigned to it
 else 
 echo $_POST['loest']; //output: 1
```

Comment: Hi Ravistm, I did what u told me, but I receive a 404 error, its because my new form action="post.php" is inside another form action called "delete", How do i solve this?

Comment: You can not embed form inside form, it will behave strangely. If you do not want to redirect it. Use Ajax to submit the details. Follow this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) for ajax